# FTP Download on C#

Tags: c#, download, ftp, file-transfer

I am trying to download files from Raspberry Pi with ftp protocol. I have to press a button to download a file Press the button and access to 'C:\Users\Monster\Desktop\ftp' is denied.' I'm getting an error. I installed the app manifest, added the necessary permission line for admin, right clicked on the folder I want to download and checked the permissions in the security section, all permissions are open. I couldn't find the reason for the error I got, can you help me, I wish you a good day.

```
 int bufferSize = 2048;
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://10.252.26.72//media/pi/Video1/video.mp4");
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("pi", "1");
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Monster\Desktop\ftp", FileMode.Create);
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        try
        {
            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Probably because you didn't close the file when you last tried it. Your `localFileStream` needs a `using`. Likewise `ftpResponse` and `ftpStream` also need `using`. Also: don't bother with the `while`, just use `ftpStream.CopyTo(localFileStream);` And don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: is `ftp` a directory?

Comment: FTP is the name of the internet protocol I use.

Comment: I am not sure. But I don't get an error about the connection in the program, I just get an error about the directory where the file should be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because you are not disposing the file stream with `using`. You should also set the `FileAccess` mode.

Also the loop is unnecessary, you can just use `CopyTo`.

```cs
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://10.252.26.72//media/pi/Video1/video.mp4")
ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("pi", "1");
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

using (FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse())
using (Stream ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Monster\Desktop\ftp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    ftpStream.CopyTo(localFileStream);
}
```

Comment: Same error. Access denied to path 'C:\Users\Monster\Desktop\ftp'. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Are you sure your user has access to the path and that no other app has it open?

Comment: yes, I gave all permissions

Comment: "I gave all permissions" doesn't fill me with confidence: you shouldn't need to add permissions for your own desktop.

Comment: I am installing app manifest for Winform and running it for admin. For the file printing process, I right click on the folder where the printing will be done and click on advanced from the security section.

Comment: I saw all permission on folder.I am using a user with all necessary permissions for file printing. Are there any other permissions I need to do?

Comment: Not sure. Sounds like you got something going on there with admin and not admin users, remember that `Desktop` is private to each user. Maybe just select a folder where you know everyone has permissions